# EditText SetText getting null value. Retrieving value via php from sql

Tags: android

I've tried everything that comes to mind, I've researched for 2 days now. I am new to Android. My final cry for help I am turning to the masters on Stackoverflow. Guide me.

Background.java

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {     
        String update_id = params[1];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(update_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("id","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(update_id, "UTF-8");
            OS.write(data.getBytes());
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            OS.close();
            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            is.close();


            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(inputLine);
            }

            return "update";}
      @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          AccountDetailsFragment ac = new AccountDetailsFragment();
          ac.receiveDetails(sb);}
```

AccountDetailsFragment.java

```
public class AccountDetailsFragment extends Fragment{

EditText update_id, update_address, update_name;
String id = "";
String idd ,namee ,addresss, login_id;
View v;
public AccountDetailsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void receiveLoginID(String id){
    this.login_id = id;
}

public void receiveDetails(StringBuilder sb){
    String[] strArray = sb.toString().split(Pattern.quote("split"));
    idd= strArray[0];
    namee= strArray[1];
    addresss= strArray[2];

    System.out.println("-*-*--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");
    System.out.println(idd);
    System.out.println(namee);
    System.out.println(addresss);
    System.out.println("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    v = lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_details, container, false);

    update_id = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_id_edit);
    update_name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_Name_edit);
    update_address = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_address_edit);

    getActivity().setTitle("Account Details");

    Button update = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String method = "update";
            Background background = new Background(getContext());
            background.execute(method, login_id);

            System.out.println("*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/");
            System.out.println(idd);
            System.out.println(namee);
            System.out.println(addresss);
            System.out.println("*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/");

            update_id.setText(idd.toString());
            update_name.setText(namee.toString());
            update_address.setText(addresss.toString());

        }
    });

    return v;
}}
```

Update.php

```
<?php 

     require "init.php";
     $update_id=$_POST["id"];

     $sql_query="select * from test where id = '$update_id'";

     $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo $row["id"];
       echo ("split");
       echo $row["name"];
       echo ("split");
       echo $row["address"];
   }
   } else {
        echo $update_id;
   }
  ?>
```

Logcat

```
I/System.out: */*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/
07-25 15:55:09.367 5914-5914/com.syntillate.aazif.aazifapp I/System.out: null
07-25 15:55:09.367 5914-5914/com.syntillate.aazif.aazifapp I/System.out: null
07-25 15:55:09.367 5914-5914/com.syntillate.aazif.aazifapp I/System.out: null
07-25 15:55:09.367 5914-5914/com.syntillate.aazif.aazifapp I/System.out: 
*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.syntillate.aazif.aazifapp.AccountDetailsFragment$1.onClick(AccountDetailsFragment.java:115)
```

Comment: I think you are getting null value

Comment: Did you try calling php script from browser? Do you get expected output?

Comment: System.out.println(idd);
System.out.println(namee);
System.out.println(addresss); what is the output of this line?I think you got the null values & try to  idd.toString()).  instead of toString() use String.valueof(idd);

Comment: String valueOf (Object obj)
Returns the string representation of the Object argument.
if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

Comment: You are getting null values of idd, namee, adresss so it returns null pointer exception. Check your php code,

Comment: It's returning a null. Data is not being fetched from sql. I don't see anything wrong in the php. I can't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change `onPostExecute()` to this

`@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          receiveDetails(sb);
    }`

and also make `Background` an inner class if it's not already.

**You were doing this:**

`AccountDetailsFragment ac = new AccountDetailsFragment();
          ac.receiveDetails(sb);`

creating a new instance of `AccountDetailsFragment` and calling `receiveDetails()`
it doesn't change the values ( idd,namee & addresss) in the calling class.

Comment: It is not an inner class. It is a class on it's own. Help me understand why I should make Background an inner class. What will be the difference.

Comment: If it was an inner class then it could access `receiveDetails` of outer class directly. If you don't want to make it inner class make `receiveDetails` static  and call it like `AccountDetailsFragment.receiveDetails(sb)`

Comment: If I make receive details static, then I won't be able to access the global variables, mainly the view. But I could try setting the view once again inside the receive details class and check if it works.
Also I found out there was an error fetching data from database. Its returning a null.

Answer (score 1):

Your doInBaground() func is returning String value "update". That will come to onPostExecute(String result) method, where you will get result as "Update". receiveDetails(StringBuilder sb) of AccountDetailsFragment class, in that you are splitting the string using the below condition.

String[] strArray = sb.toString().split(Pattern.quote("split"));

strArray array is getting null since split function won't returns with any thing with respect to result found from the onPostExecute().

Comment: It shouldn't be null because sb is a global variable, once data is fetched via php, it is saved in sb. Then I am simply passing the sb to the receiveDetails method in the AccountDetailsFragment class. Issue is with the fetching of data from sql database. Nothing is being fetched

Comment: In that case, Put a log inside while() where sb is appending. To cross check it, insert a log inside onPostExecute() and receiveDetails() methods. If it's printing null, then it might be issue with back end script..

Comment: It is printing null. Back end script as in?